# How can I manipulate password manager data for testing?

Tags: passwords

Is it possible to manipulate the password manager's data in Chrome and IE? Chrome's UI only allows me to modify the password, but not the account name or the host.

Some background: we are trying to test a site that recently changed all login id (was a customer number, will be email). Some users still have their old login id stored in their password managers, which is not valid anymore. We are trying to simulate the behaviour of a password manager entering the old id for the user, so some JavaScript can identify this case and help the user convert her login id.

Answer (score 0):

The browser stores the password and the username in a set linked to a site. If you have a new username for that same site, that is a new username/password set. Unless you build  a piece of code that will associate the old username with the new one and capture the old password and automatically use it for the new username, the only other way would be for the customer to manually enter the new credentials.